# Check whether entire div is viewable for the user

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to check whether the `div` is entirely visible to the user? I mean the scroll bar is positioned so that the entire `div` fits inside the viewport.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is exactly what this was created for:
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

Comment: Wow that's pretty cool. Here I was, rolling my own for this question, when it already exists. +1

Comment: Hmm ... Can i also check if its entirely in the viewport? Not only a small portion?

Comment: Try this one: http://patik.com/blog/within-viewport-javascript-and-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

You need to check positions for the scrollbar and the div in question, and compare them in the `scroll` event handler:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var bottom = top + $(window).height();
    var dtop = $('#mydiv').position().top;
    var dbottom = dtop + $('#mydiv').height();

    if (dtop>=top && dbottom<=bottom) {
        alert('okay!');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/dMwMb/